# Dotnet Core on Ubuntu and Apache configuration

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to host a simple Hello World on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

So far I have built the .NetCore application as a Self Contained Deployment release and ftp'd to my server inside /var/www/CoreWebsite

I have configured an existing Apache configuration inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mySite with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.myWebSite.co.uk
        ServerAlias myWebsite.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/CoreWebsite
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000

        #Other directives here
#        Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside my Program.cs I have the following:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseUrls("http://*:4000")
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
```

I have restarted the Apache Service and all I am getting when i navigate to myWebsite.co.uk is a 503 Service unavailable. I am not sure if I have to enable something for kesteral to be running, or enable a pass through?
This is a fresh installation and I haven't activated, or installed anything other than copying the files to the server...

Comment: Dotnet core web server does not need Apache. From your code, the.net core application is hosting a web server on port 4000.

Comment: OK so it looks like I have to run the site on Port 5000 and configure this in the Program.cs and my apache config file. I also have to start the site with "dotnet mysite.dll"...

Comment: See your code `.UseUrls("http://*:4000")`. This is where you mentioned port 4000. I don't think Apache should be in the picture in your case. Try uninstall/disable Apache and your program should still work.